# maven-war-plugin complains about missing assembly descriptor

Tags: java, maven, maven-war-plugin

I'm currently not using any assembly plugin in pom.xml, but I get this error:

```
[INFO] Reading assembly descriptor: src/main/assembly/assembly.xml
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error reading assemblies: Error locating assembly descriptor:           src/main/assembly/assembly.xml

[1] [INFO] Searching for file location:     C:\Users\yue\Documents\idgar_project\src\idgarsec_war\src\main\assembly\assembly.xml

[2] [INFO] File: C:\Users\yue\Documents\idgar_project\src\idgarsec_war\src\main\assembly\assembly.xml does not exist.

[3] [INFO] File: C:\Users\yue\Documents\idgar_project\src\idgarsec_war\src\main\assembly\assembly.xml does not exist.

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Currently I don't have anything in the src/main/webapp directory, instead, this content is found at some other directory. Why does it complain about assembly when I'm not using it in pom.xml?

The original pom.xml is rather long, here's the part where it uses maven-war-plugin

```
<build>
        <finalName>idgarsec</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/classes/**,WEB-INF/jsscripts/**,WEB-INF/themes/**</packagingExcludes>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>../idgarsec/webapp/WEB-INF/jsscripts/</directory>
                            <targetPath></targetPath>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                        </resource>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>../idgarsec/webapp/WEB-INF/themes/</directory>
                            <targetPath>themes</targetPath>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                        </resource>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>../idgarsec/webapp/WEB-INF/</directory>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: What does your pom.xml look like?

Comment: What phase:goal are you executing when getting this error?

Comment: I just do the mvn clean install and this error returns. Thanks

Comment: What makes you think it is the `war plugin` that is giving this error?  Looks for `assembly plugin` in your pom and post the snippet.

Comment: I'm not using any assembly plugin in the pom.xml right now; the only plugin is maven-war-plugin in this pom.xml.